# How do I get a Google Drive App's Open URL?

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

I am hoping to programatically open a drive file with a particular app using the Google drive APIs.

The aim is to mimic the GUI drive method of launching an app using the "Open With" context menu for a selected file.

While I can get a list of the available apps using apps [list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps/list), the [app resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps#resource) doesn't detail the Open URL as far as I can work out.

Does anyone know if it is possible to obtain the Open URL using the APIs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you have the scope set for drive.apps.readonly you should be able to use the File method getOpenWithLinks to discover the URLs. Just testing it now, the getOpenWithLinks method isn't available on the File class. I wonder if it has been deprecated? Certainly I can't find evidence of it being so.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getOpenWithLinks()

Revision: the getOpenWithLinks methods are available again in revision 75 of the v2 drive API.

Comment: Thanks @leeper it would seem like the way to go, but the methods not available for me either (Drive API v2).

Comment: How frustrating, the method getOpenWithLinks() is an undefined method and I cannot find any other way to get this information. I am using Drive API v2 and have the drive.apps.readonly scope specified. Does anyone have any suggestions for resolving this?

Comment: As if by magic the openwithlinks methods seem to have been resurrected in revision 75 of the v2 drive API, so @groundcontrol your problems should be solvable.